# How to run Karma server without starting any Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, jasmine, tdd, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to pass the `--grep=PATTERN` flag to `karma run`, so that only a specific tests gets executed. But if I start my karma server with `karma start karma.conf.js`, all Jasmine unit tests get executed immediately. As I have several hundred tests, this takes too long.

Question: How can I start the karma server and do not run any tests, but rather run only tests when I invoke `karma run`?

Comment: This is not even nearly an answer, but I'm just curious. I run 600+ quite heavy tests which include randomly some angular, DOM operations and asynchronous waits in less than 2 seconds on a quite slow virtual machine (1 core, 6GB of RAM, Win7). Haven't you thought about checking your tests performance? And could you please define how long does it takes to run your tests?

Comment: The test code involves websocket operations; I have a custom messaging scheme developed over ws which are the units under tests so no way of mocking them; the clients talk to a server which has build in delays as well as client built in delays to simulate certain networking behaviour; i.e. race conditions if you try to perform an operation from two clients simultaneously etc; unfortunately those tests need also to run serially to avoid races with the testing backend server. Anyways, this is not related to the question. I find it hard to believe that karma+jasmine do not provide a TDD workflow

Comment: FYI; I switched to mocha and am using the nodeJS based mocha runner, which allows me to run a single test by passing the `--grep` flag on the cmdline level. Karma+jasmine story remains to be sad :(

Comment: did you consider creating a new `karma.config` file that append only the spec file that you want to test. this is clear quick and dirty suggestion

Comment: spec file != one unit test. still, multiple tests will get run. I admit I do occasionally uncomment tests in order to work around the problem, but I would have never imagined jasmine is so not suited for solid TDD.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you would prefer is to run a single test at a time via karma/jasmine using the terminal. If this is correct, this is what I do to run single file tests.

**Note:** I use gulp to spool up Karma, but this should still work for just using the global karma.

Here is my **gulp** method as well if you chose to use that.

```
gulp.task('karma', function (done) {
  karma.start({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
  }, done);
});
```

In my **karma.config.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {

  config.set({

  basePath: '',

  frameworks: ['jasmine'],

  // Note the **setFilesUpForTesting** function below. Just change this.
  files: setFilesUpForTesting(),

  ... the rest of file
} // end of module!!!!!
```

--> Now below the module, in the same **karma.config.js** file add the following

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------ >
// Below code is for running either single or all test files.
// To run a single test, just pass in the test file name like so...

// If the test file name was rs-test-me-now_test.js
// To spool up Karma you would enter

// gulp karma --single-test=rs-test-me-now

// To just run all tests
// gulp karma

var fixedPath = [
  'public/js/jquery.js',
  'public/js/jquery-ui.min.js',
  'public/js/foundation.min.js',
  'public/js/angular.min.js',
  'public/js/angular-mocks.js',
  'public/js/angular-route.min.js',
  'public/js/angular-sanitize.min.js',
  'public/js/angular-cookies.js'
  // all the files you want to include when tests run. I removed most of mine, but left some for reference.
];

var baseTestPath = 'public/test/'; // This is the path from root to your test/spec folder that contains all your tests.

function setFilesUpForTesting(){
  fixedPath.push( testPath());
  return fixedPath;
}

function testPath(){
  return singleTestPath() || fullTestPath();
}

function fullTestPath(){
  // If your root folder was butter, and all your tests were labeled
  // like my_file_spec.js, and all your specs were in a folder under root
  // called bread, then the path below would be
  // 'butter/bread/**/*_spec.js' Got it?
  return  'public/test/**/*_test.js'; // change this to suit your path.
}

function singleTestPath(){
  var passedArgument = process.argv.filter(function(item){ if(/--single-test=/.test(item)){return item; }});
  if( isEmpty( passedArgument )){ return false; }
  return baseTestPath + '**/*' + fileName( passedArgument ) + '_test.js';
  // change above to fit your path.
}

function fileName( argument ){
  if( !argument ){ return; }
  return argument[0].replace('--single-test=', ''); // Change single-test if you want to.
}

function isEmpty( array ){
  return array.length === 0;
}
```

When I want to run tests, I then just run the following

> For single file tests
>   **gulp karma --single-test=test-me-now**

```
// when test-me-now_test.js is the file name.
// and root/pulblic/test/   has all my test files and test folders.
// or root/bread/butter/ and file is called test-me-now_spec.js as in the other example I gave above.
```

Hope this helps someone. Ask questions if you can't get it up and running.

**UPDATE**

I just used karma from the command line and this works as stated above when using gulp as well.

If karma is accessible from the command line you can now do this if you implement the karma.config.js file above...

**Note:** I have to use karma **start** not **run**,

```
karma start (will run all tests)
// or for a single test file
karma start --single-test=my-test-file-name // but without the _test.js or _spec.js whatever you call your files. I had reasons for doing this, but you can change the functions above to accept the complete file name if needed.
```

**Note:**

You can also change the wording after "--" in --single-test=
just make sure you update the karma.config.js info I shared.

Comment: For anyone finding that `start` still runs all their tests, check that you don't have a `browsers` element in your `karma.config.js`. It appears that this can cause it to run all tests and then exit.

Answer (score 1):

Well to get the server running is fairly easy. All you need to do is modify your `karma.conf.js` file. If you add the following then it'll start the server without executing any of the tests.

`singleRun : true`

Now when you run it'll ready the server, but not actually run any tests. It'll also provide you with a browser window all ready to start running. Hitting **debug** will start running the tests.

[image]

I've never tried to run individual tests, but I've just verified that using `karma run` on its own triggers them all on my server. So if you restrict the set down with `karma run` then you should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself, as there is a solution now: Focus tests (https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html).

You can replace your `describe()` with `fdescribe()` to run a single test suite, or for executing a single test you can replace the `it()` with a `fit()`:

```
fit("This test is executed on its own because it is prefix with f (focus test)", (done) => {
     done();
});
```